# How can I count views for individual video when there are multiple videos on the same page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, wordpress

I couldn't find a plugin to show video views for individual video when there are multiple videos on a single page. Almost all available counter plugins are for the page or post so, I decided to try it myself. But then I ran into the following trouble:

I somehow succeeded on increasing the counter on click of the play icon using jQuery, then I tried to pass that incremented view value to be saved on my database via AJAX, but no luck.

Can someone please look at these code and help point me to what I'm doing wrong:

Child THEME TEMPLATE CODE

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: All Videos Template
 */
get_header();
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Attach click event listener to play icons
    $('.video-item .play-icon').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var videoContainer = $(this).closest('.video-item');
        var videoId = videoContainer.data('video-id');
        var viewCountElement = videoContainer.find('.view-count');

        // Send AJAX request to update view count
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'update_view_count',
                post_id: videoId
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // Update view count in the container
                viewCountElement.text(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Error occurred during AJAX request.');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php
        // Query to retrieve all attachments
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'video',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
          /*  'orderby'        => 'rand', // Randomize video listing*/
        );

        $video_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($video_query->have_posts()) :
            ?>
            <div class="video-grid">
                <?php
                while ($video_query->have_posts()) :
                    $video_query->the_post();
                    $video_url    = wp_get_attachment_url(get_the_ID());
                    $attachment_page_url = get_permalink();
                    $attachment_page_title = get_the_title(get_post()->post_parent);
                    
                    // Check if the attachment URL starts with the 'escort' slug
                    if (strpos($attachment_page_url, '/escort/') !== false) :
                        // Get the video views count
                        $video_id = get_the_ID();
                        $video_views = (int) get_post_meta($video_id, 'wpzu_video_views', true); // Modified meta key
                        ?>
                        <div class="video-item">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($attachment_page_url); ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                <video id="video-<?php echo esc_attr($video_id); ?>" src="<?php echo esc_url($video_url); ?>" controls loading="lazy"></video>
                            </a>
                            <div class="video-details">
                                <h2>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url($attachment_page_url); ?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                        <?php echo esc_html($attachment_page_title); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </h2>
                                <p class="view-count" data-video-id="<?php echo esc_attr($video_id); ?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_html($video_views); ?>&nbsp;Views
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script>
                        document.getElementById('video-<?php echo esc_js($video_id); ?>').addEventListener('play', function() {
                            // Increment the video views count
                            var viewCountElement = document.querySelector('.view-count[data-video-id="<?php echo esc_attr($video_id); ?>"]');
                            var currentViewCount = parseInt(viewCountElement.innerText.replace('Views: ', ''));
                            var newViewCount = currentViewCount + 1;
                            viewCountElement.innerText = 'Views: ' + newViewCount;
                            // Send AJAX request to update the view count in the database
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: ajaxurl,
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {
                                    action: 'update_view_count',
                                    video_id: <?php echo esc_js($video_id); ?>,
                                    view_count: newViewCount
                                },
                                success: function(response) {
                                    console.log('View count updated successfully.');
                                },
                                error: function() {
                                    console.log('Error occurred during AJAX request.');
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        </script>
                        <?php
                    endif;
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php
        else :
            echo 'No videos found.';
        endif;
        ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

AJAX CODE IN FUNCTIONS.PHP of child theme

```
// Enqueue the JavaScript file for AJAX
function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom-ajax-script', 'customAjax', array( 'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts' );

// Update view count via AJAX
function update_view_count_ajax() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta'; // Replace 'wpzu_' with your desired prefix

    if (isset($_POST['post_id'])) {
        $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);
        $video_views = (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT meta_value FROM $table_name WHERE meta_key = 'video_views' AND post_id = %d",
            $post_id
        ) );
        
        $video_views++;
        
        $wpdb->update(
            $table_name,
            array( 'meta_value' => $video_views ),
            array( 'meta_key' => 'video_views', 'post_id' => $post_id ),
            array( '%d' ),
            array( '%s', '%d' )
        );
        
        echo $video_views;
    }
    
    wp_die(); // Always include this line to terminate the AJAX call properly
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_view_count', 'update_view_count_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_view_count', 'update_view_count_ajax' );
```

Thank you

PS.
Database type = MySQL

Comment: In your JS file, `ajaxurl` is supposed to be `customAjax.ajaxUrl` based on the localization in your functions.php.

Comment: Still doesn't work. No error log. Views only works on browser, once page refreshed views are lost. Views not updated in database.